# Shell script to find difference between version provided as string e.g. 102.19.23, 102.19.22

Tags: linux, bash, shell

{ enter code hereenter code here need help for shell script
I am working on a application deployment automation shell script. Application version is in format like 102.19.022 ,  102.19.021  format.
I want to write a shell script where a user will provide version in string format that needs to deployed (e.g 102.19.23) and script will convert it into numeric and compare this version with current system version (e.g 102.19.022). Based on this script will perform checks where it will compare both versions and displays numeric difference. If both versions are same then script will fail as version that needs deployed is already deployed in system. If current deployed version is 102.19.022 and user is trying to deploy 102.19.024 then it should calculate difference and if it higher than 1 then it should fail. If difference is 1 then it should proceed ahead. }

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and ask a specific question. "need help" is not a specific question. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score -1):

```sh
function checkver() {
    local VER1=$1 VER2=$2
    VER1n=$(echo "${VER1}" | sed -e "s/\.0/\./g" -e "s/\.//g")
    VER2n=$(echo "${VER2}" | sed -e "s/\.0/\./g" -e "s/\.//g")
    if [ "${VER1n}" = "${VER2n}" ]; then
        echo "same version"
    elif [ $(( VER2n - VER1n )) -eq 1 ]; then
        echo "diff is one, good"
    else
        echo "diff is not one, bad"
    fi
}

$ checkver "102.19.022" "102.19.23"
diff is one, good

$ checkver "102.19.22" "102.19.24"
diff is not one, bad

$ checkver "102.19.022" "102.19.22"
same version
```

Comment: RohitBuwa, does this help you at all? If so, please accept it. Thank you!